# bs-select (angular-strap) dropdown open by default when page load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-strap

I am using the plugin provided from [github](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/selects).

How can I default open the dropdown when page loads?

I tried different options like bs-show="true" then get Id of the select and add click event, but nothing seems to be working.

```
<span class="text-bold" id="godVar">
            SLA
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-model="model"
            ng-change=""
            data-html="1" data-multiple="1" placeholder="Select SLA" bs-show="true"
            bs-options="type for type in ::filters" max-length=1 bs-select id="test">
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
        </span>

$scope.test= angular.element("#test");
$scope.test.click();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```js
$timeout(function() {
   angular.element('#test').trigger('mousedown')
}, 0);
```

this solution requires jQuery included, but since you are using `click()` you have included that already.

here is a demo -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/ScHtNPYksBXx3RqM8sCT?p=preview**